# What is the best situation where you have to use a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm currently preparing for a big project in angularJS, and I'm really confused with what angularJS directives is for?

Just a clarification, or an example will really help alot.

Comment: Also take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at this in the first place: http://blog.angularjs.org/2012/11/about-those-directives.html

Maybe you could think about directives like little macros which improve classic HTML syntax.

Directives are used to replace static HTML elements with more modular, reusable **parts of functionality.**

Think of a more-or-less complex form which should be dynamic and which you would like to avoid to retype all the time. That would be a pretty good scenario for declaring a directive.
Directives are further the only place to interact with the DOM

Of course that's just a very basic example. Directives are far more than shorthands for the lazy programmer :). They can add heavy complexity and functionality to otherwise static elements and are a good way for implementing DRY code.

**Edit:**

You can use directives not only by creating custom elements like `<myDirective>` but also by restricting them to attibutes or classes. You could then link a function to them:

```
app.directive('myDirective',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A', // Attribute
    link: function(){
        // do something great
    }
  }
})
```

[This](http://www.egghead.io/video/AoDh1T_0Obg) and other interesting stuff about directives (as well as many more topics) is pretty well explained at [egghead.io](http://www.egghead.io/)

**Further reading and watching:**

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive 
http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/use-cases-of-angularjs-directives 
http://www.codinginsight.com/angularjs-directives/ 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives
http://www.befundoo.com/university/tutorials/angularjs-directives-tutorial/ 
http://www.egghead.io/

Comment: Yeah I think it is also used for codes that needs to repeat, I think I'll take a look at the link you've provided. Thanks Sprrot!

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look first at the documentation: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive 
Then take a look at some examples, like this one which focus only on directives: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yg-R1gchccg